# ffmpeg: Decoding specific AVProgram from the hls stream

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding, video-player, m3u8, http-live-streaming

I am developing a player based on ffmpeg.

Now I try to decode hls video. The video stream has several programs (AVProgram) separated by quality. I want to select one specific program with desired quality. But ffmpeg reads packets from all programs (all streams).

How can I tell ffmpeg which streams to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using disard field in AVStream structure:

```
_stream->discard = AVDISCARD_ALL;
```